# Bootlooped Samsung galaxy s2 t989D

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, data-recovery, boot-loop

I have the Samsung Galaxy S2 T989d and my phone is stuck in a bootloop with CyanogenMod. I want to get some pictures off of the internal SD before I wipe it and install the stock rom. I tried getting them off of CWM by mounting my phone but it doesnt work for some reason. I can mount my micro SD from my phone but I can't mount my internal memory.

Help would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wiping or performing a factory reset via CWM shouldn't touch any of the data on the internal sd card. However, performing a factory reset from within the ANdroid settings will wipe all personal data on the SD card.

Use ODIN to flash a stable version of either the Stock ROM or one designed especially for your device. That should at least allow you to boot the phone normally.

Comment: Thanks! if it does wipe the personal data off of my phone should will it leave my nandroid backups so i can go back just in case? and also will the Darkside Super Wipee remove all the data on my internal SD card?

Comment: I don't believe your nandroid backups will be affected. it does depend on where they were saved. I'm unable to reply to your second question in the comment having never used Darkside. Good Luck. Please post back with results of what you finally did so others can be helped in the future.

Comment: i think they are on the external sd card and thats okay:) thank you.  I will once i get this figured out.  I posted on xda aswell and recently ive been getting quite a few replies and ive gotten another fix so im going to try one and see what happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after alot of research on XDA i have finally fixed my phone.  Thanks for answering my questions Sparks! soo what i did was i deleted cache partitions and did a factory reset through CWM and i also deleted Dalvik Cache.  Then I put the new rom onto an external SD card and flashed it on my phone through CWM and now i have Mr. X's gingerbread.  But sadly my phone is no longer unlocked so now i have to figure that out :(  If anyone has the same problem and uses this fix, i suggest using Mr.X because his OS is already rooted so it saves you the time.  Oh and btw i did get to keep my pictures :).  Also to anyone who does any type of flashing or anything through CWM MAKE SURE YOU MAKE A NANDROID BACKUP BEFORE YOU DO ANYTHING!!!

Heres the link for Mr.X's gingerbread already rooted for Samsung T989 Telus:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1356739